# selected text and xy coordinates

Tags: javascript, coordinates, selectedtext

how to get a selected text and xy coordinates of the word in the same time??

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Which word? What if you select a paragraph? What (X, Y) do you want in that case? The start of the selection? Its end, where mouseup occurred? Then just use .pageX and .pageY. Otherwise, see [Coordinates of selected text in browser page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6846230/coordinates-of-selected-text-in-browser-page).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just googled it:

```
var txt = "";

if (window.getSelection) {
    txt = window.getSelection();
} else if (document.getSelection) {
    // FireFox 
    txt = document.getSelection();
} else if (document.selection) {
    // IE 6/7 
    txt = document.selection.createRange().text;
}

txt = txt.toString()
```

There is no simple way to get X/Y coordinates of the selected text. Because it dependes on its container position and size, text font, text layout, and many many other variables.

Comment: This doesn't get you the selected text, except in IE. In other browsers it returns a `Selection` object, on which you can call `toString()` to get the selected text. You also haven't answered the other, harder, part of the question.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, I just didn't tested the code, because it was very trivial.
Regarding the harder part of the question, I've got no answer for this... :(

Comment: I've seen this done before over here: http://openshakespeare.org/work/hamlet so it's not a question of IF it's a question of HOW. Would like to see this answered.

Comment: Actually, just figured out they're getting the clientX of the mouse when the mouseup event is fired. Smart hack.

Comment: For the harder part of the question, see [Coordinates of selected text in browser page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6846230/coordinates-of-selected-text-in-browser-page)

Answer (score 1):

To expand on @MatuDuke's answer, you can get the position of the selected text like so:

```
var txt = window.getSelection(),
    range = txt.getRangeAt(0),
    boundary = range.getBoundingClientRect();

// Available positions:
// boundary.top
// boundary.bottom
// boundary.left
// boundary.right
```

These will give you pixel values relative to the viewport. However, it doesn't seem to work within text areas, a problem I'm currently trying to solve.

Comment: this worked well for me, except the method is range.getBoundingClientRect()

Answer (score 0):

I am using this jQuery plugin http://plugins.jquery.com/node/7411 for a project and it seems to be working flawlessly. You could use jQuery to get the position of mouse http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Mouse_Position

Here is some sample code I have worked on

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.textselect.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $('#select').bind('textselect click', function(e){
                console.log(e.text);
                console.log(e.pageX);
            })
        });
    </script>
    <!-- Date: 2010-11-05 -->
</head>
<body>
    <div id="select">
        This is a simple select test
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you give me an example without jquery??

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.textselect.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $('#select').bind('textselect click', function(e){
                console.log(e.text);
                console.log(e.pageX);

                var selected_text = e.text
                var original_text = $(this).text();
                var parts = original_text.replace(e.text, "/").split("/");

                for(i in parts) {
                    console.log(parts[i])
                }
            })
        });
    </script>
    <!-- Date: 2010-11-05 -->
</head>
<body>
    <div id="select">
        This is a simple select test
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```