# Coordinates of selected text in browser page

Tags: javascript, html, selection, textselection

I need the coordinates in pixels of the beginning of the text selection (anywhere on the page, not in a textarea).

I tried using the cursor coordinates but this didn't work quite well because the cursor coordinates and the beginning of the selection are not always the same (for example when a user drags over a text).

I hope someone has the solution!

Answer (score 69, accepted):

In IE >= 9 and non-IE browsers (Firefox 4+, WebKit browsers released since early 2009, Opera 11, maybe earlier), you can use the [`getClientRects()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-view/#the-getclientrects-and-getboundingclientrect-methods) method of `Range`. In IE 4 - 10, you can use the `boundingLeft` and `boundingTop` properties of the `TextRange` that can be extracted from the selection. Here's a function that will do what you want in recent browsers.

Note that there are some situations in which you may wrongly get co-ordinates `0, 0`, as mentioned in the comments by @Louis. In that case you'll have to fall back to a workaround of temporarily inserting an element and getting its position.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NFJ9r/132/

Code:

```
function getSelectionCoords(win) {
    win = win || window;
    var doc = win.document;
    var sel = doc.selection, range, rects, rect;
    var x = 0, y = 0;
    if (sel) {
        if (sel.type != "Control") {
            range = sel.createRange();
            range.collapse(true);
            x = range.boundingLeft;
            y = range.boundingTop;
        }
    } else if (win.getSelection) {
        sel = win.getSelection();
        if (sel.rangeCount) {
            range = sel.getRangeAt(0).cloneRange();
            if (range.getClientRects) {
                range.collapse(true);
                rects = range.getClientRects();
                if (rects.length > 0) {
                    rect = rects[0];
                }
                x = rect.left;
                y = rect.top;
            }
            // Fall back to inserting a temporary element
            if (x == 0 && y == 0) {
                var span = doc.createElement("span");
                if (span.getClientRects) {
                    // Ensure span has dimensions and position by
                    // adding a zero-width space character
                    span.appendChild( doc.createTextNode("\u200b") );
                    range.insertNode(span);
                    rect = span.getClientRects()[0];
                    x = rect.left;
                    y = rect.top;
                    var spanParent = span.parentNode;
                    spanParent.removeChild(span);

                    // Glue any broken text nodes back together
                    spanParent.normalize();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return { x: x, y: y };
}
```

**UPDATE**

I submitted a WebKit bug as a result of the comments, and it's now been fixed.

https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=65324

Comment: Works perfectly on single line selections, but when you select multiple lines (starting from somewhere half-where in the first line) it shows the coordinates for the beginning of the first selection-line not the beginning of the selection it self....


I know that is probably because of the getBounding function but is there any way to change that?

Comment: @Bouke: Ah, fair point. I've updated my answer to do as you asked, by collapsing the range to a single point at the start before getting its position.

Comment: That works great on firefox, but now it doesn't seem to work on webkit browsers anymore... Seems like this is a webkit bug, maybe I need to use your older script as a fallback.

Comment: @Bouke: You're right. WebKit's `getBoundingClientRect()` returns `null` for collapsed ranges, which is unhelpful. Working on it...

Comment: I have tried this code. It is returning always `x: 0, y:0` even the caret position is moved in firefox 20.0.1. Please have a look at this [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16212871/1577396) which I asked recently. I am looking for a cross-browser solution which works in IE8+, chrome and firefox.

Comment: @Mr_Green: This code is specific to selections/ranges within regular HTML content rather than textareas, as is Rangy. I don't believe it is possible to create a general cross-browser solution for getting coordinates of the textarea cursor without doing lots of tedious text measuring, which is why I haven't answered your other question.

Comment: @TimDown: we might have done just that with the [component.io textarea-caret-position plugin](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22446703/1269037) - get the (x, y) position of `selectionStart`/`selectionEnd` in a textarea, cross-browser, and without using jQuery.

Comment: @TimDown There's more than an issue with textareas, I'm afraid. Run  this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NFJ9r/) in Chrome and click to the left of "here" (which is in bold), without selecting text. You'll get `0, 0`. It is more easily reproducible in Chrome but the basic problem is that if a zero-width range is **not** in a text node, then the rectangle will have `0, 0` coordinates. I can't reproduce it in FF with a simple mouse click because it prefers to set the caret inside text nodes on clicks, but it could also happen in FF if the selection is manipulated programmatically.

Comment: @Louis: Yes, I've seen that too. The workaround is to temporarily insert an element and get its position. I'll add a note to the answer.

Comment: @TimDown there is an error when the caret is in an empty div

Comment: Maybe add a comment on the `if (sel)` mentioning it targets only [some versions of IE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535869(v=vs.85).aspx)?

Comment: @DanDascalescu This answer predates the existence of IE 11, which was the first not to support `document.selection`, but IE 11 does support Range and `Range.getClientRects` so there should be no problem with the actual code. I'll update the text though. Fair point about `rects[0]`, that's an oversight.

Comment: @TimDown thanks for this solution. You have solved all my problems. I don't know why, but it is not working correctly in complex html in iOS for example http://copytaste.com/aw8146

Answer (score 24):

**The above answer by TimDown does not work if the caret is in an empty element.**

The code below solves the problem. Note how it is almost identical to TimDown's solution except that this code checks the `range.getClientRects()` array has `length>0` before calling `range.getClientRects()[0]`

```
function getSelectionCoords() {
    var sel = document.selection, range, rect;
    var x = 0, y = 0;
    if (sel) {
        if (sel.type != "Control") {
            range = sel.createRange();
            range.collapse(true);
            x = range.boundingLeft;
            y = range.boundingTop;
        }
    } else if (window.getSelection) {
        sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.rangeCount) {
            range = sel.getRangeAt(0).cloneRange();
            if (range.getClientRects) {
                range.collapse(true);
                if (range.getClientRects().length>0){
                    rect = range.getClientRects()[0];
                    x = rect.left;
                    y = rect.top;
                }
            }
            // Fall back to inserting a temporary element
            if (x == 0 && y == 0) {
                var span = document.createElement("span");
                if (span.getClientRects) {
                    // Ensure span has dimensions and position by
                    // adding a zero-width space character
                    span.appendChild( document.createTextNode("\u200b") );
                    range.insertNode(span);
                    rect = span.getClientRects()[0];
                    x = rect.left;
                    y = rect.top;
                    var spanParent = span.parentNode;
                    spanParent.removeChild(span);

                    // Glue any broken text nodes back together
                    spanParent.normalize();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return { x: x, y: y };
}
```

Comment: Good point. Do you mind if I include that check in my answer?

Comment: @TimDown Sure you can include it in your answer.

Answer (score 6):

The code below is a simplified and modernized version of the solution given by Tim Down. It also uses a more [browser compatible selection API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7003784/does-chrome-supports-document-selection) (`window.getSelection()` instead of `window.document.selection`)

```js
type Coord = {
  x: number;
  y: number;
};

// atStart: if true, returns coord of the beginning of the selection,
//          if false, returns coord of the end of the selection
function getSelectionCoords(atStart: boolean): Coord | null {
  const sel = window.getSelection();

  // check if selection exists
  if (!sel.rangeCount) return null;

  // get range
  let range = sel.getRangeAt(0).cloneRange();
  if (!range.getClientRects) return null;

  // get client rect
  range.collapse(atStart);
  let rects = range.getClientRects();
  if (rects.length <= 0) return null;

  // return coord
  let rect = rects[0];
  return { x: rect.x, y: rect.y };
}
```