# Does chrome supports document.selection?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am new to javascript, trying to perform:

```
document.selection.createRange();
```

but `document.selection` always returns  `undefined`.

I am using latest version of chrome.

what am I doing wrong?

thanks!

Answer (score 15):

Use `window.getSelection()`, which is the most cross-browser compatible (it's supported in the current versions of all major browsers) and is [the standard](http://html5.org/specs/dom-range.html#extensions-to-other-interfaces). Chrome certainly supports it as fully as other browsers.

`document.selection` should only be used for IE < 9.

Comment: IE9 doesn't like it : SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'getSelection'

Comment: @Misi: In which case your IE 9 must be in one of the compatibility modes. In standards mode, it definitely supports `window.getSelection()`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535873(v=vs.85).aspx#methods

Comment: function markSelection ( txtObj ) {
  if ( txtObj.createTextRange ) {
    txtObj.caretPos = document.selection.createRange().duplicate();
    isSelected = true;
  }  How to chage this to document .getselection()

Answer (score 3):

Try `document.getSelection()` or `window.getSelection()`.

Here's a quick example that I tested in chrome

http://jsfiddle.net/hgDwx/

Comment: i've tried using both window.getSelection and Document.getSelection but also the function getRangeAt(index) does not functioning. 

i've done: 
var selObj = document.getSelection(); 
var selRange = selObj.getRangeAt(0); 
alert(selRange); 

what do you say?
thanks

Comment: im getting rangeCount value always zero

Comment: @adi I've added an example that was test in chrome

Comment: I assume selection is just the class of the object which is retrieved with document.getSelection() like below:

var s = document.getSelection();
s."Any of properties or methods listed in link below";

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection

Answer (score 3):

Browser support for the `selection` object based on IE11 and Chrome 87.04280.141

| Member | IE | Chrome |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `document.selection` | yes | no |
| `window.selection` | no | no |
| `document.getSelection()` | no | yes |
| `window.getSelection()` | no | yes |

This is the easy part.
The problems come when you are trying to use any methods, f.e. `getRange()` which exists for `document.selection` (IE compatible), but doesn't exist for `document.getSelection()`, so for Chrome you need a workaround.

Comment: mm... it seems like IE [supports](https://caniuse.com/?search=getSelection) both `window` and `document`'s `getSelection` methods - are you sure about the browser support table?

Answer (score 1):

Use `window.getSelection()` instead.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.getSelection