# createRange function is not working in other browsers except IE

Tags: javascript

I have a text box. When I write first text , then java script function will fire to check whether it is a number.

For IE , the following code is returning -1 value, But Other browsers it does not alert any value. Please help me

```
var selected = document.selection.createRange();
var decInSel = selected.text.indexOf('.');
hasNegInSel  = selected.text.indexOf('-') != -1;
alert(decInSel);
```

Comment: Is your "textbox" an `input` ? or a `textarea` ?

Comment: Then why not just use `document.getElementById('id').value` instead of selected text ?

Answer (score 1):

`document.selection.createRange()` is IE < 9 only ... you the following function for cross browser support

```
function getSelectedText() {
  if (window.getSelection) {  // all browsers, except IE before version 9
    var selectionRange = window.getSelection ();                                        
    return selectionRange.toString();
  } else {
    if (document.selection.type == 'None') {
        return "";
    } else {
        var textRange = document.selection.createRange();
        return textRange.text;
    }
  }
}
```

[Reference here](http://help.dottoro.com/ljefwsqm.php)

So your full code would look like this :

```
var selected = getSelectedText()
var decInSel = selected.indexOf('.');
hasNegInSel  = selected.indexOf('-') != -1;
alert(decInSel);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

> window.getSelection()

[Does chrome supports document.selection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7003784/does-chrome-supports-document-selection)

Answer (score 0):

Other browsers use `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` properties of the text box. You can get the selected text in a text box in those browsers using the following:

```
var input = document.getElementById("textBox");
var selectedText = input.value.slice(input.selectionStart, input.selectionEnd);
```