# JavaScript: how to adapt working function (IE) for Firefox and/or Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox, getselection

I am using the following function to get the selected text range within a contenteditable div. 
This works fine in IE but not in Firefox and Chrome.

Can anyone tell me how I would need to adjust this so that it works in either both FF and Chrome or at least one of them (besides IE) ? It it would work in current versions there that would be enough.
The idea with this is to replace the selected text through another function that gets the "selTxt" from here.

**The function to get the selection (working in IE):**

```
function GetSelection() 
{
selTxt = '';

if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined") 
{
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    if (sel.rangeCount) 
    {
        var container = document.createElement('div');
        for (var i = 0, len = sel.rangeCount; i < len; ++i) 
        {
            container.appendChild(sel.getRangeAt(i).cloneContents());
        }
        selTxt = container.innerHTML;
    }
} 
else if (typeof document.selection != 'undefined') 
{
    if (document.selection.type == 'Text') 
    {
        selTxt = document.selection.createRange().htmlText;
    }
}
return selTxt;
}
```

**The function to replace the selection (this seems to be the issue):**

```
function EditBold()
{
    var newTxt = '';
    btnID = 'btnBold';

    GetSelection();     

    if (selTxt.toLowerCase().indexOf('<strong>') == -1)
    {
        document.selection.createRange().pasteHTML("<strong>" + selTxt + "</strong>");
    }
}
```

Many thanks for any help with this, Tim.

Comment: What are you seeing when running this code in FF and Chrome? The `window.getSelection()` is supported by both FF and Chrome.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. When testing it in FF and Chrome it looks like it doesnt do anything but also doesnt give me an error.

Comment: Update: I think I found the issue. This is not in the function that gets the selection but in the function that uses it. I will add this above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use a variable `selTxt` in the `EditBold()` function, but don't have it declared inside the function.  If the value is supposed to be what is returned by GetSelection(), use the following:

```
var selTxt = GetSelection();
```

Comment: While using `var` should be done, I think referencing `selTxt` will still work because `selTxt = '';` from `GetSelection()` is going to set a global variable on `window`, which will be accessible in `EditBold()`. Use of a global variable like that is, of course, bad practice.

Comment: Thanks for the notes on that. This is declared as a global variable outside these functions which is why i didnt paste it here.

Comment: I also checked on using the variable as you suggested but this doesnt make a difference in FF and Chrome.

Comment: the offending line is         `document.selection.createRange().pasteHTML` I don't think that is even supported in FF or Chrome

Comment: Check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7003784/does-chrome-supports-document-selection).  Try it with `document.getSelection().createRange().pasteHTML`

Comment: Can confirm. `document.selection` is `undefined` in Chrome, but [`document.getSelection()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.getSelection) returns a [`Selection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection) object.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Matthew - that's the missing piece ! Works perfect for me !