# On click select Div is not working on IE

Tags: javascript, css

I have a code for on click select all text. But unfortunately not working on IE. can anyone give the fix for this.

Need a fix for all browser compatable.

This script is working on below IE 9.0. Not working for IE 10 and above. so kindly give the solution.

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>autoresizing textarea</title>
<style type="text/css">
#divid {
    display:inline-block;
    border: solid 1px #000;
    min-height: 20px;
    width: 300px;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
 function selectText(containerid) {
        if (document.selection) {
            var range = document.body.createTextRange();
            range.moveToElementText(document.getElementById(containerid));
            range.select();
        } else if (window.getSelection) {
            var range = document.createRange();
            range.selectNode(document.getElementById(containerid));
            window.getSelection().addRange(range);
        }
    }
</script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="divid" onclick="selectText('divid')">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </div>

<div>
                                                    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text &nbsp;</div>




</body>
</html>
```

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7003784/does-chrome-supports-document-selection

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette that probably does contain the answer but it's not a duplicate. It look kind of the opposite of this question...

Comment: @T J mmm. You're right. I commented too fast.

Comment: @user3859368... Do you only want to have all the text selected onclick or you want to do something with the text user has selected manually ?

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette Yes. it is a duplicate only. but this script is working on below IE 9.0. Not working for IE 10 and above. so kindly give the solution for this

Comment: @TJ Yes. it is a duplicate only. but this script is working on below IE 9.0. Not working for IE 10 and above. so kindly give the solution for this

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to select all the text contained in the div onclick...
Just remove all your old script and change your div declaration for this :

```
<div id="divid" onclick="this.select();">
```

It's browser compatible.

**-----

EDIT**

The problem with the script in your question is that it relies on the `selection` object, which is deprecated since Explorer 11. See here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535869(v=vs.85).aspx

MSDN suggest it be "replaced by" `getSelection`, but the link to it leads to the method of the deprecated `selection` object. So...

Anyway, isn't it complicated to just select all?

Comment: Which IE version you are using?, the same code is working fine in IE8.0, I have checked.

Comment: This is a simple select() command. «this» is an object selector that can be understood as «self», in this case.

Comment: @BanwariYadav IE 9 and above only not working. i have checked with ie 11

Comment: @user3859368 «[selection is no longer supported. Starting with Internet Explorer 11, use getSelection. For info, see Compatibility changes.]» ref : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535869(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @user3859368 : Only to select all that's into your div... Just use the simple way which is browser compatible and forget about your old script. ;)