# find y coordinate for cursor position in div in UIWebView

Tags: javascript, objective-c, ios, uiwebview

I have a UIWebView with some basic html that acts as a simple editor.

```
// in initWithFrame: of UIView subclass.
_editorHTML = [@"<!doctype html>"
                   "<html>"
                   "<head>"
                   "<meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width,initial-scale=1\">"
                   "<style type=\"text/css\">"
                   "#content { font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:1em; } "
                   "</style>"
                   "<script type=\"text/javascript\">"
                   "function load()"
                   "{"
                   "    window.location.href = 'ready://' + document.body.offsetHeight;"
                   "}"
                   "</script>"
                   "</head>"
                   "<body id=\"bodyDiv\" onload=\"load()\">"
                   "<div id=\"content\" contenteditable=\"true\">%@</div>"
                   "</body>"
                   "</html>" retain];

_webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, frame.size.width, frame.size.height)];
_webView.delegate = self;
_webView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
_webView.scrollView.bounces = NO;
[_webView loadHTMLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:_editorHTML, @""] baseURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:directory]];

- (BOOL) webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    NSURL *url = [request URL];
    if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeOther) {
        if ([[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"ready"]) {

            int height = (int)_webView.frame.size.height;
            [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.getElementById('content').style.minHeight = '%dpx'", height - WEBVIEW_DIVHEIGHT_OFFSET]];

            return NO;
        }
    }
    return YES;
}
```

So, how can I determine the cursor position in my div so I can update my scrollView to make sure that the content is visible above the UIKeyboard thus not having to make the user manually scroll to keep the text in view?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get the selected range from the selection and use its [`getClientRects()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-view/#the-getclientrects-and-getboundingclientrect-methods) method.

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/timdown/xMEjD/

Code:

```
function getCaretClientPosition() {
    var x = 0, y = 0;
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    if (sel.rangeCount) {
        var range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
        if (range.getClientRects) {
            var rects = range.getClientRects();
            if (rects.length > 0) {
                x = rects[0].left;
                y = rects[0].top;
            }
        }
    }
    return { x: x, y: y };
}
```

Comment: @developerdoug: Yes. Is that what you wanted?

Comment: @IvorySantos: It may do in some browsers, but it won't in Firefox, which does not have any association between the `Selection` returned by `window.getSelection()` and selections inside textareas and inputs.

Comment: @IvorySantos: In fact it doesn't work for textareas in any browser I tried.

Comment: This only works if there is text when you hit return. If you move the cursor to the end of the line and hit enter to create some returns, it won't show an accurate value.

Comment: Awesome answer.  Worked great for my `<div contentEditable=true>`!

Comment: It is returning wrong position ( (x,y) = (0,0) ) when I type first letter, right after new line. (after return key in iOS). Any idea ?

Comment: In case of multiple <div> when we type in first row of any section it returns same i.e. y=0. But from next line i.e Line2 , Line 3 .... Line n it works perfect.

Answer (score 5):

@timdown Interestingly enough, your script always returns 0,0 for the beginning of a line. The script from [question]: [Coordinates of selected text in browser page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6846230/javascript-text-selection-page-coordinates) does return the right Y value, though.

Repeated here for ease of searching:

```
function getSelectionCoords() {
    var sel = document.selection, range;
    var x = 0, y = 0;
    if (sel) {
        if (sel.type != "Control") {
            range = sel.createRange();
            range.collapse(true);
            x = range.boundingLeft;
            y = range.boundingTop;
        }
    } else if (window.getSelection) {
        sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.rangeCount) {
            range = sel.getRangeAt(0).cloneRange();
            if (range.getClientRects) {
                range.collapse(true);
                var rect = range.getClientRects()[0];
                x = rect.left;
                y = rect.top;
            }
        }
    }
    return { x: x, y: y };
}
```

Comment: In my tests, the answer from the different question linked here *does* fix the problem, but the piece of code repeated here does *not*. The trick is to add a DOM element then get its position, go look at the code here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6847328/135712

Answer (score 1):

This solution is an evolution of the accepted answer.  Fixes the newLine issue in WebKit.

```
function getCaretClientPosition() {
    var x = 0, y = 0;
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    if (sel.rangeCount) {

        var range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
        var needsToWorkAroundNewlineBug = (range.startContainer.nodeName.toLowerCase() == 'p'
                                           && range.startOffset == 0);

        if (needsToWorkAroundNewlineBug) {
            x = range.startContainer.offsetLeft;
            y = range.startContainer.offsetTop;
        } else {
            if (range.getClientRects) {
                var rects = range.getClientRects();
                if (rects.length > 0) {
                    x = rects[0].left;
                    y = rects[0].top;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return { x: x, y: y };
}
```