# Get caret coordinates on a contenteditable div through javascript.

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable, caret

I've been searching a lot but i could't find a way to get (X,Y) coordinates for the caret on a content editable div,there's a lot of content on the web about this,but the problem none of the pages i found get the coordinates according to the top of the div,so my question in a simpler way is:

**How can i get the (X,Y) coordinates of the caret on a contenteditable div,but the Y coordinate must be calculated according to the top of the div and not from the top of the visible part of the page?**

**Note 1:** I need specially the Y coordinate.

**Note 2:** I can only use pure javascript,no JQUERY.

**My way:**

I haven't found a direct way to do this,so as a workaround i thought on getting the Y coordinate according to the visible part of the page and the hidden part of the Div and sum the results(I'm currently working on this but i getting no luck!).

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6846230/javascript-text-selection-page-coordinates - you just need to subtract div position from returned coordinates.

Comment: No it's no a duplicate question.The accepted answer does not answer my question.I need to get coordinates even if a part of the DIV is hidden.

Comment: Its not a duplicate

Comment: What do you mean by "(X,Y) coordinates for the caret"? Coordinates in pixels? Caret has height at least, so what Y coordinate would you like to get?

Comment: I want position at each instance when I wrote in an Contentediatble

Comment: If part of the div is hidden as you say, does the height need to ignore the hidden portion of the div?

Comment: no it shouldnot

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16302076/xy-caret-coordinates-inside-a-contenteditable-div

Comment: Maybe you should take a look at http://ichord.github.io/Caret.js/ It seems to use jQuery but maybe you can dig into their code ;)

Answer (score 13):

try this:

```
var selection = window.getSelection(),
    range = selection.getRangeAt(0),
    rect = range.getClientRects()[0];
```

in the rect var you should find the position:

`rect.left` -> for the x coordinate
`rect.top` -> for the y coordinate

there is also `rect.width` and `rect.height`. In case the user has some text selected `rect.width` will be >0.

Comment: my client rects have a length of 0

Comment: Slightly weirdly, rect.width can be > 0 if the caret is at the end of a line too. The selection seems to contain the "virtual" newline added by wrapping the text. So a better way of checking if there's text selected is to see if the start and end containers and offsets are both equal. Not massively relevant, but curious!

Answer (score 10):

1. get selection and range

   ```
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    var range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
   ```
2. insert collapsed div

   ```
    var div = document.createElement(...)
    range.insertNode(div)
   ```
3. get div coordinates
4. remove the div

Comment: I had to combine this with the below answer and got getClientRects() to work on the temp div.

Answer (score 0):

to find on (X,Y) coordinate and using pure javascript, this function I found may do the trick:
in this [Source](https://www.kirupa.com/html5/get_element_position_using_javascript.htm) you will find all explanation about their process *(the code below is taken from the same source)*:

```
function getPosition(el) {
  var xPos = 0;
  var yPos = 0;

  while (el) {
    if (el.tagName == "BODY") {
      // deal with browser quirks with body/window/document and page scroll
      var xScroll = el.scrollLeft || document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
      var yScroll = el.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop;

      xPos += (el.offsetLeft - xScroll + el.clientLeft);
      yPos += (el.offsetTop - yScroll + el.clientTop);
    } else {
      // for all other non-BODY elements
      xPos += (el.offsetLeft - el.scrollLeft + el.clientLeft);
      yPos += (el.offsetTop - el.scrollTop + el.clientTop);
    }

    el = el.offsetParent;
  }
  return {
    x: xPos,
    y: yPos
  };
}
```

Comment: can you provide a any example on jsfiddle

Comment: I need it in a content editable I have tried this code before

Answer (score -1):

try this
http://plnkr.co/edit/T2S7sKByTIesEVC6R8jQ?p=preview

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
  var pointer = document.querySelector('#marker')
  function checkCaret() {
    if(document.getSelection()) {
      if(document.getSelection().baseNode) {
        var position = document.getSelection().baseNode.parentNode.getBoundingClientRect()
        pointer.style.top = position.top + 'px'
      }
    }
  }
  setInterval(checkCaret, 500)
});
```

Comment: "Note 1: I need specially the Y coordinate." it gives y coordinate