# How to get the position of caret in a content editable div which contains br, img, and #text?

Tags: javascript, html

In my content-editable div, the structure is like

```
div
   <br>
   <img>
   Hello world
   <br>
   <br>
   <br>
   Hello again
   ...
```

I hope to get the current x,y coordinates of the caret.

I tried to use

```
var currentSelection = window.getSelection();
var currentRange     = currentSelection.getRangeAt(0);
var insertContainer  = currentRange.startContainer;
```

and look at

```
insertContainer.offsetTop
```

but it does not work for #text and br node, because the insertContainer is just the parent div.

Could anyone help?

Comment: Can you provide a Fiddle with an example of what you've tried?

Comment: possible duplicate of [XY Caret Coordinates inside a contenteditable div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16302076/xy-caret-coordinates-inside-a-contenteditable-div)

Comment: Take a look at this thread:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16736680/get-caret-position-in-contenteditable-div-including-tags][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16736680/get-caret-position-in-contenteditable-div-including-tags