# How to get current position of cursor in contenteditable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Placed my code here http://jsfiddle.net/50zb8xxo/8/

Want to detect cursor position before execution of javascript

Found example here https://stackoverflow.com/a/6847328/2118559 but code is long. Trying to do the same with some short code.

Found some short examples, but none works

Tried these

```
<div id='editable' style="width: 180px; height:70px; border: 1px solid #ccc;" contenteditable></div>


var editable = document.getElementById('editable'), selection, range;
var editable = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
var editable = window.getSelection();
alert ( editable );
```

In all cases alert see blank popup

Here https://stackoverflow.com/a/3976125/2118559 some code, but also not short...

Comment: All codes are long. Trying to get some short code (if possible)

Comment: The code in those answers is long because that's what it takes to build the desired functionality. You can't just demand shorter code and expect it to work.

Comment: OK. Now clear, will try with the longer codes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It will help.

```
var ins = document.getElementById('editable').selectionStart;
```

Its working

Comment: In Firefox see blank popup...

Comment: exactly what do you want?

Comment: To see cursor position. If I type one character popup 0, two characters, popup 1 and so on. With `alert ( document.getElementById('editable').selectionStart );` see blank popup. As understand it is not possible with some short code...

Comment: wait bro, let me do that in fiddle and give you the link