# Get the coordinates of selection in CKEditor

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, tooltip, coordinates, selection

When a text is selected I want a span to appear above it (like a tooltip). This is the span:

`var span = new CKEDITOR.dom.element.createFromHtml('<span style="position:absolute; display: none; " >Tooltip</span>');
span.setStyle('border', '2px solid black');
span.setStyle('width', '50px');
span.setStyle('height', '50px');`

It must be added above the selection but I can't find a way to get the coordinates of the selection:

```
span.setStyle('display', 'none');
var editorSel = editor.getSelection();
var selElement = editorSel.getSelectedElement();
if (editorSel.getSelectedText() != '') {
setTimeout(function() {
     //Some way to get the coordinates
     span.setStyle('top', top + 'px');
     span.setStyle('left', left + 'px');
     span.setStyle('display', 'block');

     var ranges = editorSel.getRanges();
     var range = ranges[0];
     range.insertNode(span);
}
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the editor window object from CKEditor using the following, although there may be a more direct way:

```
var win = editor.window.$;
```

From there, you could use `getSelectionCoords()` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6847328/96100):

```
var coords = getSelectionCoords(win);
```