# get absolute cursor/cater pixel position in editable UIWebView by using javascript in iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview, hook

Is there any way to get absolute (with respect to the UIWebView's window, not Div) cursor pixel position, .

Comment: Look into this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6846230/coordinates-of-selected-text-in-browser-page/6847328#6847328

Comment: It is not working in iOS mobile if our html does not have plain or simple format.  I am trying with this http://copytaste.com/aw8146

Comment: don't know why. Earlier I have added in a complex html for creating DOC editor in iOS & it was working fine.\