# Get position of caret on the screen - not the textbox on tinymce

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

I am working on a project where I am using tinyMCE https://www.tiny.cloud/.

I want to get the caret position inside the TinyMCE editor on the screen not within the textbox as I want to be able to position a div based on where the caret is on the screen.

The only things I've found is getting the caret position from inside the text editor in order to create range of text within the editor which isn't what I'm after.

Comment: You should take a look at the [`document.execCommand(...)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand) function.

Comment: @Titus I've had a look at the link but I'm not sure how that helps with what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: You could use the `insertText` or `insertHTML` to insert something at the cursor position in a `contentEditable` element.

Comment: I'm not trying to insert content into the editor. I am just wanting to get the caret  position on the screen to overlay a `div` over the editor near to where the caret when a certain character is typed - I'm not editing the editor content

Comment: I see, in that case, you could get the coordinates of the first/last range in the selection. Something like `document.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).getBoundingClientRect()`

Comment: Thanks I've given that a try, but all the coordinates it returns are 0.

Comment: If I'm not mistaking, **tinyMCE** uses an `iframe`, you'll have to access that `iframe`'s document instead of the top document.

Comment: Hmm. I've looked at http://archive.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3:method.tinymce.Editor.getDoc which seems to do what you suggest so its now `tinymce.get('txtNote').getDoc().getSelection().getRangeAt(0).getBoundingClientRect();` but all the co-ordinates are still 0

Comment: I've tested it on https://www.tiny.cloud/ `tinyMCE.editors[0].getDoc().getSelection().getRangeAt(0).getBoundingClientRect()` returns the coordinates. You have to select something in the example editor first.

Comment: Ah that's the problem, I'm not selecting anything, I'm just typing a specific character and that causes a div to appear

Comment: My mistake, I don't mean you need to select (highlight) something, you just need to focus the `contentEditable` element, make sure the caret is somewhere inside of it.

Comment: Wouldn't it be already be in focus as I'm typing into it?

Comment: Yes, that is true unless you're focusing something else inside the key listener callback. Also, you can get 0 coordinates in some cases when the focused node is a text node that contains spaces. This solution has a fix for that https://stackoverflow.com/a/6847328/1552587

Comment: @Titus Got it working with what you said, I wasn't changing focus so I didn't have to worry about that. I think when I tried it previously my browser cached the original. Can you make it an answer what you suggested and I can accept it.