# Inspecting Firefox Components.interfaces.nsIDOMWindowUtils.screenPixelsPerCSSPixel value in Javascript Scratchpad

Tags: firefox, scratchpad

I am using Firefox Scratchpad to understand the scaling behavior that
results when the user types the `CTRL-PLUS` and `CTRL-MINUS` keys.
In Javascript Scratchpad, I'm evaluating a snippet of Javascript code that accesses the
`Components.interfaces.nsIDOMWindowUtils.screenPixelsPerCSSPixel`
property like this:

```
var util = window.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIInterfaceRequestor).getInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIDOMWindowUtils); 
util.screenPixelsPerCSSPixel
```

In Scratchpad typing `CTRL-L` after the last `l` in `screenPixelsPerCSSPixel` above results in an Exception:

```
Exception: The operation is insecure.
```

(Note that the current active Firefox tab is pointing to http://www.google.com).

The `devtools.chrome.enabled` flag is set to true in this
context, but that does not seem to matter as an Exception is still being thrown.

What do I need to do in order to get Javascript Scratchpad to display
that value?

This is intended only to be temporary to gain understanding during a
debug ritual. Set aside for now the obvious question of "Why is it a
security risk to show a scaling factor?". I'm only after getting at
the value from the confines of standard, and safe, Firefox controls
such as enabling/disabling `about:config` values that I can easily
undo later when I'm done.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer I found:

Accessing the `window` variable from the Scratchpad scope whose
Environment (see its Environment menu) is set to Content yeilds one
type of object, while if Environment was set to Browser, a different
type of object is in play (`CTRL-L` on it in Scratch pad reports it is
of type `ChromeWindow`).  The `window.content` object is the content
object relative to the `ChromeWindow` object.

The value of

```
....QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIInterfaceRequestor).getInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIDOMWindowUtils).screenPixelsPerCSSPixel
```

relative to the `window` object (`ChromeWindow`) object returns
`1`, while calling it on the `window.content` shows something other
than 1 and show that scaling is involved.

(EDIT: I relocated the Javascript code that used to be here; see below.)

To demonstrate using the value, I've provided some sample Javascript in an answer to my other question at [Finding top-level X Window x/y coordinates of CTRL-F text in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14294786/257924)